# Are there any hotkeys to align the corner of the window with the corner of the screen in Win10?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Are there any hotkeys to align corner of the window with the corner of the screen in Win10? I am using image recognition with screen capture and I want the objects to be exactly on the same spot from launch to launch.

Comment: How about `windows + up`?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN , this is is game running in windowed mode. I can not make it full screen.

Comment: `windows + up` is FOR windowed mode.  If it doesn't do what you expect, the game is probably eating your key strokes.  Try it with another application like your browser or notepad.. you will at least see what @Nagabhushan_S_N is talking about.

Comment: I know that this combination will switch between windowed and full screen modes. I can not make my game full screen because of computation limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `WINDOWS + LEFT`, followed by `WINDOWS + UP`. This will align the window in the upper left hand side of the screen. You can use `WINDOWS + RIGHT` instead of `WINDOWS + LEFT` to align the window in the upper right hand corner of the screen.

P.S. You don't have to actually let go of the WINDOWS key in between the shortcuts, however you do have to let go of the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider having a look at [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). AutoHotkey is a utility that allows you to define custom hotkeys for a wide range of actions in Windows.

For instance, the following is an example script which can move the currently active (focused) window to the upper left corner of the screen without maximizing it (unlike <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>▲</kbd>) via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>:

*ex. upper_left.ahk*

```
^F4:: WinMove, A, , 0, 0
```

Just save the command above in a normal text file with the `.ahk` extension. After installing AutoHotkey, you should be able to double-click this file to enable the hotkey and action specified.

*Command Breakdown*

- `^F4` - Hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. You can (potentially) use any hotkey you wish.
- `A` - The window title to move. `A` is the currently active (focused) window. Note that there are ways to specify a particular window if needed.
- `, ,` - Blank placeholder for identifying a window through its window text (unused in this command).
- `0, 0` - the X and Y screen coordinates to move the window to. You can specify your own set screen coordinates as well.

**Overriding <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>▲</kbd>**

As already mentioned, you can use almost any hotkey you like. So, assuming you didn't really want to use the "maximize" functionality of <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>▲</kbd>, you could override it with `#Up` in place of `^F4`:

*ex. win_up_upper_left.ahk*

```
; Override Win + Up Arrow (which normally maximizes a window)
#Up:: WinMove, A, , 0, 0
```

---

*Note that any line that starts with a `;` is considered a comment in AutoHotkey and is ignored.*

---

**Other Corners And Centering**

You can use additional commands if you want to position the window in other corners of the screen. You can even center the window if you wish.

In particular, you can use `GetWinPos` to discover a window's width and height, then use those values in conjunction with `A_ScreenWidth` and `A_ScreenHeight` (the screen width and height, as determined by AutoHotkey) to position the window correctly.

The example script below demonstrates creating hotkeys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> → <kbd>F8</kbd>)
which move the currently active (focused) window to all four corners of the screen, as well as centering it:

*ex. four_corners_and_centering.ahk*

```
; The default Windows 10 Taskbar Height (40 pixels) plus the approximate
; default window bottom border (decoration) thickness (~15 pixels).
Taskbar := 55

; Upper Left
^F4:: WinMove, A, , 0, 0

; Upper Right
^F5::
    WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
    WinMove, A, , (A_ScreenWidth - Width), 0
    Return

; Lower Left (No Taskbar)
^F6::
    WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
    WinMove, A, , 0, (A_ScreenHeight - Height)
    Return

; Lower Left (With Taskbar)
; ^F6::
    ; WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
    ; WinMove, A, , 0, (A_ScreenHeight - Height - Taskbar)
    ; Return

; Lower Right (No Taskbar)
^F7::
    WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
    WinMove, A, , (A_ScreenWidth - Width), (A_ScreenHeight - Height)
    Return

; Lower Right (With Taskbar)
; ^F7::
    ; WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
    ; WinMove, A, , (A_ScreenWidth - Width), (A_ScreenHeight - Height - Taskbar)
    ; Return

; Center the active window in the middle of the screen.
^F8::
    WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
    WinMove, A, , (A_ScreenWidth/2)-(Width/2), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(Height/2)
    Return
```

---

**AutoHotkey References**

- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Variables](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Screen) (Screen)
- [WinMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm)
- [WinTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm)
- [GetWinPos](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetPos.htm)