# How can we center align a window to the right or left of the screen in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, alignment

I found these scripts from Anaksunaman that center and move windows around on the screen.

[Centering Windows - StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/1567121/are-there-any-hotkeys-to-align-the-corner-of-the-window-with-the-corner-of-the-s/1742892#1742892)

Any help on how to center a window the the far left or right of the screen?

I played around with one to center it to the right, but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't depending on where the window opens. Sometimes it centers it a little below the top right corner.

```
;Right Middle (No Taskbar)
 ^2::
 WinExist("A")
 WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
 WinMove, (A_ScreenWidth - Width), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(sizeY/2)
 Return
```

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: What is `sizeY`. This doesn't work unless that variable is defined somewhere as the Height of the Window.

Comment: I don't know. I'm pretty sure I copied that part from another script I was testing it with and got it to work. Is it not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.

I changed the height from `(A_ScreenHeight/2)-(sizeY/2)` to `(A_ScreenHeight/2)-(Height/2)`.

Here's the new script to center to the left or right w/ no taskbar.

```
;Right Middle (No Taskbar)
 ^1::
 WinExist("A")
 WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
 WinMove, (A_ScreenWidth - Width), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(Height/2)
 Return


;Left Middle (No Taskbar)
 ^2::
 WinExist("A")
 WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
 WinMove, A, , 0, (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(Height/2)
 Return
```